# Show different page if first time visit

Tags: php, cookies

I found a snippet of code that redirects if it's the first visit, but when I tried to use it, it just stayed at that code. I don't really understand too much about the cookies and how it works, so maybe you can help! Here's the PHP code:

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['FirstVisit'])) {

    $_SESSION['FirstVisit'] = 1;

    header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");

    // Don't forget to add http colon slash slash www dot before!

    }

?>
```

So how could I fix it so if it's your first visit to the site it brings you to a certain page, and if not, the default?

Comment: Your not setting any `cookie`, your setting a `session` (which sets a cookie, but shouldn't be persistent).

Comment: `// Don't forget to add http colon slash slash www dot before!
` why? relative paths `./index.php` can be used within a location header

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime']))
{
    setcookie("firsttime", "no", /* EXPIRE */);
    header('Location: first-time.php');
    exit();
}
else
{
    header('Location: site.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

It will check if you have a cookie named "firsttime" and if not, it will create it and redirect to your FIRSTTIME page... If yes, it will just redirect you to the website...

**EDIT 2021**
Please don't use this old method and either use a framework or better code. This is 10 years old now.

Comment: Question, I thought the header function could only be used before anything else happened? In the above case, why have the exit function afterwards if it would be relocated to that link? It should never run the exit function if it actually relocated. Sorry, don't know much about headers.

Comment: @Andy I'm not using the exit() function in my code but yes, you must put any header() before any other code because it will make problems with <head> tag...

Comment: Ohh, it means: the PHP header() goes before the <html> tag, and before the <!DOCTYPE> tag too.

Comment: Ohh, I see what your saying, so as long as its before any output to the window, it is valid. Thanks.

Comment: This has 13 upvotes, and is marked as the correct answer... but it's not working for me. I get an error when I try to send back to the index.php if it's not the first load: The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: @norsewulf Please provide a link to view the result... Like a public web server. If possible, enable errors reporting. It may be due to the configuration of the server or the browser.

Comment: This solution worked great for what I needed. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['FirstVisit'])) {

    //show site for the first time part
    $_SESSION['FirstVisit'] = 1;
    header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");

    // Don't forget to add http colon slash slash www dot before!

    } else { Show normal site }

?>
```

You just make an if statement to check whether there is a session set, if not, you know its there first time. Though, since it is not a cookie, anytime you quit the browser, it will assume it is the first time, even if it is never the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If sessions/cookies are to difficultly you can save the IP of the visitor. When IP exist show page 1 when IP is new redirect to other page?

Answer (score 1):

For more information see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) { // no cookie, so probably the first time here
        setcookie ('visited', 'yes', time() + 3600); // set visited cookie

        header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
        exit(); // always use exit after redirect to prevent further loading of the page
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

    @session_start();
    $url = 'http://blah.com/default/';

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['Visited'])) {
        $_COOKIE['Visited'] = 1;
        $url = 'http://blah.com/firstvisit/';
    }

    header("Location: {$url}");

  ?>
```

Comment: Please don't suppress warnings. Everytime you do that a kitten dies.

Comment: That was not constructive at all, the only reason it is suppressed is because we have no idea where this code is going, and if inserted in the wrong spot it could throw warnings about headers already being sent. Sorry your kitten is dead.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-
ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script> 

<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime']))
{
setcookie("firsttime", "no", /* EXPIRE */);
header('Location: first-time.php');
exit();
}
else
{
?>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>text</p>
</div>
<?
}

?>
```

@ Frederick or PeeHaa would the above script also work to bring up a window before they enter the site rather than a page.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  You posted an "answer", but it sounds like you actually have a question(?). If so, you should [open a new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.