# setting a value for index.php page

Tags: php

is there a way set a value for the index.php page on its first load?

i would like index.php it to load like so "index.php?subject=1" when it loads for the first time.
as this value will change as they move around in the site i don't want it to be a fixed value.

some one sugested

```
 if(empty($_SESSION['visited'])) {
    //DO STUFF 
    $_SESSION['visited'] = true; }
```

i cant seem to get that to work with my function.

find_selected_page()

```
function find_selected_page () {
    global $current_subject;
    global $current_page;
    if (isset($_GET["subject"])) {
    $current_subject = find_subject_by_id ($_GET["subject"]);
    $current_page = find_default_post($current_subject ["id"]);
} elseif (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $current_subject = null;
    $current_page = find_page_by_id ($_GET["page"]); 
} else {
    $current_page = null;
    $current_subject = null;
}
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/session/session.php');
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db/dbcon.php');
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/functions.php');
    $context = "public";
    find_selected_page ();
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>   
<?php   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/style.php'); ?>
<body>
<?php   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/header.php'); ?>
<?php   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/nav_ribbon.php');?>
    <div id="p2dbg">
        <div id="p2dcontent">
            <div class="p2dcontent">
        <h1><?php echo htmlentities($current_subject ["menu_name"]); ?></h1><br />
                <?php if ($current_page) { ?>
                        <p><?php echo nl2br($current_page ["content"]); ?></p><br />
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            This page does not exist! please slect a page from the menu.
                        <?php } ?>                      
            </div>
        </div>
<?php   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do have `session_start();` in there somewhere, right?

Comment: Sessions would be the best use have you used session_start before the code?

Comment: set `$_SESSION['subject']=1` after `if(empty($_SESSION['visited'])) {`

Comment: You'll probably make better use from using actual cookies and not session cookies. Oh heck, why not both then?!

Comment: Check this out on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752418/1415724

Comment: yes session_start in the first thing in the sessions.php file hmm didnt thing of $_SESSION['subject']=1 ill try that

Comment: @ShawnS Good. Then you should have mentioned that in your question then. If you have another similar issue later down the road, do remember to make a note of it, it will save me a lot of keystrokes (**darn arthritis**). ;-)

Comment: @fred will try to do that next time don't know what proper structure is i put it in sessions.php that way any were i need the session i know the start_session is going to load with it.

Comment: @ShawnS Good stuff ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting everything to null if your value isn't passed, just assume the default value:

```
// Set this to the value you want as your default
define("DEFAULTSUBJECT",1);
function find_selected_page () {
    global $current_subject;
    global $current_page;
    if (isset($_GET["subject"])) {
        $current_subject = find_subject_by_id ($_GET["subject"]);
        $current_page = find_default_post($current_subject ["id"]);
    } elseif (isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $current_subject = null;
        $current_page = find_page_by_id ($_GET["page"]); 
    } else {
        $current_subject = find_subject_by_id (DEFAULTSUBJECT);
        $current_page = find_default_post($current_subject ["id"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: gave this a try well i got an error! that is more then i got for  if(empty($_SESSION['visited'])) {
    //DO STUFF 
    $_SESSION['visited'] = true; }... so its a good place to start. just have to track down the error and figure out how to fix it.