# PHP Redirect if user is new to the site

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to redirect the user only if they are new to the site and have not visited it before.

What's the best way to do this? Could we create MySQL db storing IP addresses and then check against it?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `cookie` or database logs.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you !
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752418/5127494

Comment: Thank you Medrupaloscil, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could do IP addresses, however many people have Dynamic IP addresses from their ISP, and so it wouldn't be very accurate, and would also not work if they visited from a different location, say a mobile or tablet device roaming.

The other method would be to set an endless cookie on users who have visited, which you could check, but again if the user switches device, there is no guarantee the cookie will be present ( I know chrome syncs cookies between devices as long as you are logged into the browser )

So really the answer to your question is, its not possible to guarantee the user has never visited before without using user provided data, i.e. a login..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very helpful!