# First time visit open graph: How to bypass this?

Tags: cookies, facebook-opengraph

I've set up first time visit landing page via my site following this: [Show different page if first time visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752398/show-different-page-if-first-time-visit)

It works and all that but i noticed all my website pages returns open graph values from my landing page regardless of the link. I have a feeling that facebook grabs what it gets from the landing page instead of the actual link.

How do I prevent this from happening so that my open graph information will be normal again?

Additional Information: I am using instapage for the landing page. It's all showing the opengraph values under that landing page instead of the actual link of a certain page from my website.

Comment: How are the value shown? How is your web page retrieving those value? Find the source and you'll find your problem. So far as your question goes, way too broad for this forum.

Comment: @MaximeRouiller Values are show and retrieved from what i have set from instapage. Since, first time visits is set, I think facebook takes the information from the landing page instead of the actual link. The question is, how do I make this bypass my landing page's social information without me removing the first time visit redirect.

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong since I don't use instapage. Instapage is like a WYSIWYG as far as I could notice and there's no code related to this. I would highly recommend contacting Instapage support.