# Redirect user daily

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to redirect the user if it's their first time visiting that day.
Iv'e found this: [Show different page if first time visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752398/show-different-page-if-first-time-visit)

I've tried:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) { // no cookie, so probably the first time here
    setcookie ('visited', 'yes', time() + 3600); // set visited cookie

    header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
    exit(); // always use exit after redirect to prevent further loading of the page
}

?>
```

And I've also tried:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['FirstVisit'])) {

//show site for the first time part
$_SESSION['FirstVisit] = 1;
header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");

// Don't forget to add http colon slash slash www dot before!

} else { Show normal site }

?>
```

This dosen't work for me. I've pasted this code into my HTML webpage, and updated the link to work for my project. The page simply does nothing and I'm trying to figure out why.

The goal is to add a motd to my website, redirecting users to a motd page once daily. On the motd page there would be a history back button, to get them to where they were going in the first place. I don't do javascript or php, much less cookies so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that your cookie is actually getting set in the first section of code? Also, make sure it's a `.php` file and not `.html` (*Only because you said - `"I've pasted this code into my HTML webpage"`*).

Comment: There is an answer below... Just commenting to light up your HUD in-case you missed it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Info

The full spec of the desired outcome is unknown, but for international use I would suggest the following:

- You need the user's time-zone, so using JavaScript for this will suffice
- Every "landing page" for a user request should load this JavaScript which could set the cookie (if not set) - with the user's current time.
- If the cookie is set, then the JavaScript should read the cookie data and parse the text to date/time and calculate if it is "the next day" for that specific user
- You need to consider using a cookie-policy for Europe/France and inform users that cookies are being used to improve user-experience.

In order to have this specific script load for every page, it could become very complicated, depending on how your server-side handling is set up.

If you only need this for 1 specific URL (page) then it is as simple as adding this script in the HTML of that page.

I do not have enough information to know what the requirements are -or how your server setup operates, but here's the whole 9 yards:

---

## Answer

The following code snippets assumes the following:

- you have a typical "LAMP stack" installed on the hosting server
- your Apache config "allows directory overrides" (with `.htaccess` files)
- your Apache setup has `mod_rewrite` installed and enabled
- Apache+PHP has read permission of all the files created in your `docroot`
- your PHP version is at least 5.5 (or better)
- your users have JavaScript enabled (default)

If you follow the following steps, you can have it working exactly as you'd expect; just change the code and put it where needed. This will give you a solution that will work for every request, no matter the page your users visit.

In your server's `docroot` folder, create these files:

- `.htaccess`
- `handler.php`
- `cookie.js`

**.htaccess**
Open the `.htaccess` file in your favorite text editor, type in the following, and save:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !handler.php$
RewriteRule (.*) handler.php
```

**handler.php**
Type the following in your `.handler.php` file, and save:

```
<?

    $over = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
    $path = explode('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $path = (($path == '/') ? '/home.html');
    $extn = array_shift((explode('.',$path)));
    $list = # array
    [
        'html' => 'text/html',
        'css'  => 'text/css',
        'png'  => 'image/png',
        'js'   => 'application/javascript',
    ];

    $type = (isset($mime[$extn]) ? $mime[$extn] : 'text/plain');

    if (file_exists(".${path}"))
    {
        if (is_dir(".${path}") || ($path == '/.htaccess'))
        {
            header("${over} 403 Forbidden");
            echo "path: `$path` is forbidden";
            exit;
        }

        header("${over} 200 OK");
        header("Content-Type: ${type}");

        if (extn !== 'html')
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
            readfile($path);
            exit;
        }

        $text = file_get_contents($path);
        $text.= '<script>'.file_get_contents('./cookie.js').'</script>';

        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($text));
        echo $text;
        exit;
    }

    header("${over} 404 Not Found");
    echo "path: `$path` is undefined";
    exit;

?>
```

**cookie.js**
Type the following in your `.cookie.js` file, and save:

```
function cookie(name,data,days)
{
    if (data === undefined)
    {
        var prts;

        data = "; " + document.cookie;
        prts = data.split("; " + name + "=");

        if (prts.length == 2)
        { return prts.pop().split(";").shift(); }

        return null;
    }

    if (data)
    {
        var gone = "";
        var date = new Date();

        if (days)
        {
            date = (date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000))).toGMTString();
            gone = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }

        document.cookie = name+"="+data+gone+"; path=/";
        return true;
    }

    if (data === false)
    {
        cookie(name,'',-1);
    }
}
```

---

## Explanation

The `.htaccess` file points all requests to the `handler.php` file.
The `handler.php` file handles the request according to the requested path.
If it is an HTML document request, it serves the requested HTML document along with the javascript that you can use to manage your cookies

The `cookie` function works quite simple:

- To make a cookie: `cookie('some_name','some_value');`
- To read a cookie: `cookie('some_name');`
- To drop a cookie: `cookie('some_name',false);`

## Conclusion

By using the instructions and code examples above, you have enough info to build what you need.
You need a concise list of mime-types though, and better security than what the PHP code suggests, but you can use that to get started.

If you have any questions regarding all the above, kindly comment below.